# Using disableKeyguard and reenableKeyguard to lock and unlock

Tags: android

In my application I am using disableKeyguard and reenableKeyguard to lock and unlock a screen with proximity and accelerometer sensors respectively. My application working with some bugs. If user `unlocks` a screen by dragging (without using my app) then my application will not `lock` !. How to prevent this issue? How to fix this bug? plz help me.

Is there any other way to lock and unlock ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Dang over 5 years without any answers

Answer (score 0):

> reenableKeyguard
>
> void reenableKeyguard() Reenable the keyguard. **The keyguard will
>   reappear if the previous call to disableKeyguard() caused it to be
>   hidden.** A good place to call this is from onPause() Note: This call
>   has no effect while any DevicePolicyManager is enabled that requires a
>   password.
>
> This method requires the caller to hold the permission
>   DISABLE_KEYGUARD.

Your app has to be the one to call `disableKeyguard()` first, else you cannot lock it using `reenableKeyguard()`

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html